# CKEDITOR5 Uncaught ReferenceError: SourceEditing is not defined

Tags: asp.net-core, ckeditor5

I'm using CKEDITOR5. My code looks as below

When I'm using

```
plugins: [SourceEditing, Markdown],
```

I'm getting the following JS Error.

> Uncaught ReferenceError: SourceEditing is not defined

It's a .NET Core MVC Web App. I've downloaded and used the CKEDITOR5 files (not installed through NPM)

What Javascript do I need to import in order to use SourceEditing?

Any help is highly appreciated on this.

```
<script src="~/lib/ckeditor5-build-classic/ckeditor.js"></script>


<script>

var myEditor;

ClassicEditor
    .create(document.querySelector('#txtaEditor'), {
        plugins: [SourceEditing, Markdown],
        toolbar: ['heading', '|',
            'fontfamily', 'fontsize', '|',
            'alignment', '|',
            'fontColor', 'fontBackgroundColor', '|',
            'bold', 'italic', 'strikethrough', 'underline', 'subscript', 'superscript', '|',
            'link', '|',
            'outdent', 'indent', '|',
            'bulletedList', 'numberedList', 'todoList', '|',
            'code', 'codeBlock', '|',
            'insertTable', '|',
            'uploadImage', 'blockQuote', '|',
            'undo', 'redo', 'editor'], shouldNotGroupWhenFull: true

    })
    .then(editor => {
        myEditor = editor;
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

*The effect in the gif image below should be what you want.*

[image]

After my investigation, I found that installing plug-ins generally uses nodejs or online compilation. So, currently there should be no way to use `plugins: [SourceEditing, Markdown],` in cshtml file to add plugins.

It is recommended to use online compilation for non-nodejs projects, then download and replace the js and css file paths. The above effect is achieved in this way. The picture of my project structure is posted below.

[image]